# Interpretation of Feynman Slash Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors, representation-theory, spinors

I'm self-learning Relativistic Quantum Mechanics and was playing around with the Dirac equation when I noticed something.

I was trying to interpret the meaning of ${\not} \partial$. So since I can represent a 3-vector by a traceless hermitian matrix: $$\vec{x}=x^i \vec{e}_i \to X = x^i \sigma _i$$

Can I represent a 4-vector using gamma matrices?
$$\vec{x}=x^\mu \vec{e}_\mu \to X = x^\mu \gamma _\mu$$

So in the case of a covector:

$$x_\mu \vec{e}^\mu \to X = v_\mu \gamma ^\mu \equiv {\not} v$$

Therefore, ${\not} \partial$ is just the matrix representation of the covector $\partial _\mu$

Comment: Yes, you can. $\not{X}=\gamma^\mu X_\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\gamma_\nu X_\mu=\gamma_\nu X^\nu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course; people do this routinely. Read your texts on.
The essence of the map is its invertibility through
$$\operatorname{Tr} \left(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\right) = 4\eta^{\mu\nu},$$
so that
$$v_\mu ~~  \mapsto ~~ {\not} v  \equiv v_\mu \gamma ^\mu  ~~
\mapsto~~ \tfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Tr} \left( {\not} v\gamma^\nu\right)=v^\nu.$$
You know how to lower the free index.

This  parallels the elementary ubiquitous spinor map in 3D,
$$\vec{x}~ \mapsto ~X  \equiv  \vec x \cdot \vec  \sigma ~\mapsto~ \tfrac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr} X\vec \sigma = \vec x. $$